# QProcess with administrator priviledges

Tags: qt, root, privileges, administrator, qprocess

I would like to use QProcess to run a shell script from a .sh file.
The problem I have is with the user permissions. How do I prompt the user for the administrator's username and password in order to have correct privileges to use the .sh file ?

I would love to have a prompt that looks like this :
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Qt does not provide any cross-platform facilities for that yet.

Your best bet may be to put that logic into the shell script (i.e. ask a new non-Qt tagged question).

Comment: True but you can branch your code accordingly based on the OS your Qt application is running on since Linux, Windows, MacOS etc. all support some sort of rights management that you can use.

Comment: @rbaleksandar True, but then it becomes hard to use QProcess, as you need to start the process using platform-specific code, AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, but you can also use the provided tool the specific OS gives you. For example in Windows you can use `runas` to specify the user who executes the specific command.